# Rails 3: How to get external ruby script output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm doing an online-judge application and I wish to run a ruby script (or a c++, java, etc program) from a controller, save the output in a variable and compare it to a test file I have in my database.

I'm stuck with running the program and checking the answer it sends to standard output. I've tried `answer = load path`, (being "path" a variable with the path of the script) but that returns "true" instead of the stdout content; and `` answer = `ruby path` `` but it doesn't recognize the path variable.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `system("ruby #{path}")`, but be careful not to pass any user-submitted information to the path variable (or at least sanitize it thoroughly), as this can pose extremely serious security risk.

Comment: Thank you. That `#{path}` is what I was looking for. Actually just `ruby #{path}` (between backticks that for some reason I can't scape in this comment) worked for me. I supose this will work to for other compilers and interpreters right? Like c++, java, python, etc.

And thanks for the security tip too!!